# Where to store files for system app?

Tags: android

I have an application that is installed to /system/app, but is not signed with corresponding certificate to be "system" app.

Where I should store files for this app (for example, config file)? /sdcard/ is not suitable because for my case.

Device is rooted.

Comment: Why do you not simply do what all developers do: Store configs, etc. in your data directory (`/data/data/<your package name>`). Just use `SharedPreferences` for configs and check out the developer page of android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html